# How do I select content between two patterns with preg_match_all on php?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match-all

Im trying to search for two HTML tags, and also grab everything in between. When I try each of the tags separately it finds them fine, so I know that they are spelled right and exist. The problem I think is with the pattern, can someone please help me with it. 
Everything I research online seems to go right over my head. So if you could please explain how your pattern works, that would be awesome!

See code below, and if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Thanks for your time:)

```
<?php
$date= date(Y)."/".date(n)."/".date(j);
$address= "http:www.example.com/".$date;
$text_page = file_get_contents("$address");

$searchfor1 = '<li id="menuSynchronizeSwitch">';
$searchfor2 = '<li  id="footerPrevWeek';

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$pattern1 = preg_quote($searchfor1, '/');
$pattern2 = preg_quote($searchfor2, '/');

$pattern = "/^.*$pattern1.*\r*$pattern2.*\$/m";


if(preg_match_all($pattern, $text_page, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
?>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use regex to parse html, here is a link to manual(DOM), this will help you: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$pattern = '/\<li id\="menuSynchronizeSwitch"\>.*\<li id\="footerPrevWeek/si';`. Note the `/s`, which allows the dot to match newlines, which I suspect is what is causing this to fail.

Comment: Thanks that worked awesome! I just had to add a few backslashes and it worked. See code below.        $pattern = '/\<li id\="menuSynchronizeSwitch"\>.*\<li  id\="footerPrevWeek/si';

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to group each pattern with parenthesis

like this:

$pattern = "/(some pattern)/";

and you can get each group by going through the $matches array